# Visiting EU member states on German blue card visa

Tags: germany, international-travel, eu

I have German blue card visa.
Which countries I can travel without applying any visa and for how long?

Answer (score 5):

A blue card is a type of residence permit.  With a residence permit or national (type D) visa issued by a Schengen country, you can visit any other Schengen country, provided you comply with the 90/180 day rule.  Some other countries may allow holders of Schengen visas or residence permits to enter.  This notably includes the EU countries that are expected to join the Schengen area in the future, while excluding the UK and Ireland.

Comment: A clarification, time in Germany does *not* count against 90/180 if you have a German permit. So you can spend up to 90 days in Schengen states other than Germany and the remaining time in Germany.

Comment: Good point! just for the record, Ireland asked me to apply for a Visa to visit some friends (at that time I hold a BlueCard too!)  so this question is very accurate!!!!